# Add shipping method programatically after checkout - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement inserting a shipping method right after the checkout is completed. Unfortunately this is not working very well and I am not sure why. I've tried with all the hooks after checkout, but...

Here is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_order_processed', 10, 1);
function action_checkout_order_processed( $order ) {

    $item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();

    $item->set_method_title( "Безплатна Доставка - Speedy" );
    $item->set_method_id( "speedy_shipping_method" ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
    $item->calculate_taxes("0");

    $shipping_item_id = $order->add_item( $item );

    wc_add_order_item_meta($shipping_item_id, "method_id", "speedy_shipping_method");
    wc_add_order_item_meta($shipping_item_id, "instance_id", "0");
    wc_add_order_item_meta($shipping_item_id, "cost", "0");
    wc_add_order_item_meta($shipping_item_id, "total_tax", maybe_unserialize('a:1:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}}'));

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status('on-hold');

    $order->save();

}
```

This is a working code in another function so I must be having something else wrong, but not sure what.

Thanks in advance if anyone can give me a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution if anyone is having issues with this.
I modified the admin order output in includes/admin/meta-boxes/html-order-shipping.php and there I forced my custom method to be loaded on every order, so in that case the user sees the right method on the frontend, and then I successfully update the method in the backend only which is exactly what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the priority of `add_action`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_order_processed', 10, 1);
```

For more details Please see the following link.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

[do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', $wccs_custom_checkout_field_pro );](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form/)

Comment: thanks but I already tried that... it always returns me http://prntscr.com/odh2f2 empty error-message which is very weird

Comment: which priority you have put instead of 10?

Comment: Please try 99, 999, 9999 etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working with these as well.. It keeps showing me this empty error message

Comment: that's the problem, it just opens the error message box and there is no message -> http://prntscr.com/odh9ot

Comment: Hey Please try `woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form` hook as http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form/

Comment: Thanks but this is breaking the checkout unfortunately... And I need a hook that has a $order param in it so I can update the actual order

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve... But potentially try using a different hook?

`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_checkout_order_processed', 10, 1 );`

This will run your code when the customer reaches the thank you page. 
OR

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_processing', 10, 1 );
```

Will run your code when the order status changes to processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried with these but it didn't worked. 
What I'm trying to achieve is just use one method for the front end, and then update the shipping method of the order once it's successfully added.